# Flutter - Incoming call feature using Agora

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, agora.io

Hi I have created an application for video calling using agora package, I would like to know how to in flutter we can be able to show a incoming call screen or push notification. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm facing the same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue too, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I used [stacked_services](https://pub.dev/packages/stacked_services) to show a custom dialog (without context) from my service when I receive an icoming call.

I then changed the Dialog() to a Scaffold() to make it a full screen notification that was completely customizable.

Comment: Thanks, but can you give a code example? How do you handle locked screens? Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code example.